# Which Machine Learning Algorithm should I use to classify(Binary) an analog signal?

Tags: machine-learning

Currently I am trying to classify an analog signal of 128 points. It will be a binary classification of 'Yes' or 'No'. My data set is roughly 10,000 data points and is supervised. The algorithm/model I think I should use is the Linear Support Vector Machine but I am not sure.

> Is their a specific algorithm I should be use in this situation?

**Implementation:**
I am using Microsoft.ML to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

The method that you use can benefit from the fact that these 128 numbers have temporal relations. One common way to achieve this is to use discrete cosine transform (DCT)as a pre-processing step. After DCT you can use your classifier of choice. In this way given the proper use of model complexity control tools, you can achieve a more compact model with a temporal signal.

I would start with logistic regression as the baseline model and then increase the complexity if it improves the performance. SVM seems rather a reasonable choice after DCT considering the number of data points that you have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Microsoft ML but for time sequence data LSTMs or GRUs are widely applied. When you say '128 points', is that the number of features per time step or the length of each sequence to be classified?

Comment: Each data point in the set is a analog signal (128 points sampled over a time period) that maps to a label (yes or no).

Comment: A support vector machine very well may work, but I'd want to compare it with a LSTM or MLP to see if they offer any performance improvements. If you've already set up your pipeline, most ML libraries make it pretty easy to switch algorithms.